# I can receive data from controller but cannot send to controller from view with AJAX call .NET CORE

Tags: asp.net, .net, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I want to send a string type id from View to the controller, do some calculations in the relevant action in the controller, and return a string back to the view. I can receive the returnData from controller, however the parameter of the action which is 'String data' is always null. It means i cannot send data from view to controller.
Thank you for your help.

View Side:

```
var data= "some string";

        $.ajax({

            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            url: "/Identities/Ajax",
            success: function (data) {
                alert("data: " + data);
            },
            error: function (result) {
                alert("error!!");
            }

        })
```

Controller Side:

```
public JsonResult Ajax(String data)
    {
        var returnData= "some string";
        Console.WriteLine(data); // Always Null
        return Json(returnData);
    }
```

Comment: what is `data` in `JSON.stringify(data)`? Where is that defined?

Comment: Sorry @zgood I just editted it

Comment: I think the problem is that you are **not** specifing your paramater name (which is "data" in your controller action). Try passing it like this: `JSON.stringify({ data: data})`, or maybe just `{ data: data}` might work. You are currently just stringifying a string

Comment: I tried them both but the parameter is still null

Comment: Try making your action a post action by putting `[HttpPost]` above it

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work either

Answer (score 0):

You must create object first, then stringify object to pass object value to controller. Example:

```
var data= "some string";

    $.ajax({

        var objParam = new Object();
        objParam.data = data;

        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify(objParam),
        url: "/Identities/Ajax",
        success: function (data) {
            alert("data: " + data);
        },
        error: function (result) {
            alert("error!!");
        }

    })
```

Also you have to change in your controller

```
public ActionResult Ajax(String data)
    {
        var returnData= "some string";
        Console.WriteLine(data); // Always Null
        return Json(returnData);
    }
```

Comment: it's still the same

Comment: post your whole script

Answer (score 0):

Use FromBody attribute on your parameter.

`public ActionResult Ajax([FromBody]String data)`

and name parameter in your jquery part:

`data: {data: JSON.stringify(data)},`

Comment: it's still the same